# Improving the performance for the asp.net MVC 3 application

Tags: performance, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on an asp.net MVC 3 web application, i have the following two questions about the performance of my mvc application:-

1. currently i am implementing all the business logic in one model repository class ., expect that the repository implementation is quit huge (in regards to the number of lines of code), i am not having difficulties in maintaining this repository class. But my question is WILL having one repository class that implement all the business login for all entities can negatively affect the application performance comparing to having more than one repository?
2. currently i am adding the data annotation for the entities properties to implement client side validation and helper methods in partial classes and metadattypeof as i am using Db first apprach; such as

   ```
   [MetadataType(typeof(Classes_validation))]

       public partial class Class
       {
   ```

   //code does here

   , so will having more than one partial class for each entity can negatively affect the application performance?
   BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it will matter FAR more the type of activity in your methods. This can get quite difficult to deal with, why not transfer your business logic out to another class.

Comment: thanks for the reply; i do not want to have more than one repository since i am affraid of facing partial update problem incase i need more than one repositiry class in the same transaction.

Comment: Then use a unit of work pattern, its meant for this. You'll be thankful in the long run. Essentially your context class gets passed into each repository (preferably through an interface named IUnitOfWork that you create) that performs the work on it. Then at the top level you simply SaveChanged() on your context to submit all the work. Google: unit of work entity framework  and you'll find tons of implementations. Dont throw all code in one place to become one huge class, future developers will curse you : )